# Used by another process when compressing with PS

Tags: powershell

I got following PS script to move files, then compress and delete.

```
#get the time stamp
$dateTimeStamp = "$((Get-Date).toString("yyyy.mm.dd-HH.mm.ss"))"
Write-host "Time stamp $dateTimeStamp"
#create a folder with the time stamp
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $Src\$dateTimeStamp
#move files to the new path
Get-ChildItem -Path $Src\*.log | Move-Item -Destination $Src\$dateTimeStamp
#compress file
Compress-Archive -Path $Src\$dateTimeStamp -DestinationPath $Src\archived\$dateTimeStamp.zip
#remove files
Remove-Item -Path $Src\$dateTimeStamp -recurse
```

But when compressing files, Im getting following error.

```
ZipArchiveHelper : The process cannot access the file 
'D:\shared\logs\2023.00.28-15.00.26\system-error.log' because it is being used by another process.
At C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\
Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive\Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive.psm1:697 char:30
+ ... sArchived = ZipArchiveHelper $subDirFiles.ToArray() $destinationPath  ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (D:\shared\logs\...error.log:String) [Write-Error], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CompressArchiveUnauthorizedAccessError,ZipArchiveHelper
```

I'm running the ps script as Admin, is there is a way to avoid or kill the process that using the file during the compress process.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered the same issue during my first attempt but was unable to replicate it. I found a few articles depicting that `Move-Item` performs asynchronously so you might attempt to incorporate `Wait-Process` or `Start-Job` to ensure the files have been moved prior to attempting to `Compress-Archive`. Alternatively, you could omit the `Move-Item` altogether as shown in solution 1.

```
# solution 1 (preferred)
$src = Get-Item -LiteralPath 'C:\Logs'
$date = Get-Date
$logs = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $src -Filter "*.log"

[void](New-Item -ItemType Directory ('{0}\{1:yyyyMMdd-HHmmss}' -f $src.FullName, $date) -Verbose)
Compress-Archive -LiteralPath $logs.FullName -DestinationPath ('{0}\{1:yyyyMMdd-HHmmss}\logs.zip' -f $src.FullName, $date) -WhatIf
Remove-Item -LiteralPath $logs.FullName -WhatIf

# solution 2
Move-Item -LiteralPath 'C:\TEMP\rhel-9.2-x86_64-dvd.iso' -Destination 'C:\TEMP\ISO\RHEL.iso' | Wait-Process -Verbose

# solution 3
$move = Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
    Move-Item -LiteralPath 'C:\TEMP\rhel-9.2-x86_64-dvd.iso' -Destination 'C:\TEMP\ISO\RHEL.iso'
} 
$move | Wait-Job | Receive-Job -Wait -AutoRemoveJob
```